# How to avoid wasted zero-initialization when reading a file into a vector<char>

Tags: c++

I found that most examples online implement reading files to vectors like this:

```
std::ifstream file("example.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

std::vector<char> buffer(size);
if (!file.read(buffer.data(), size)) do_something()
```

but in this code there's a zero-initialization when calling `buffer(size)`, and if I use `reserve()` instead, the vector will not have the right value of size().

So anyway I can avoid this zero-initialization but still using a vector, instead of using malloc?

Comment: `reserve()` increases the capacity not the size. You can insert elements into the vector until the capacity is full, after that it reallocates.

What is so bad about zero initialization though?

Comment: because I'm a efficiency paranoid.

Comment: there isn't going to be a clean way to do this. You can make a helper class with an empty default constructor `struct uninitialized_char{char data; uninitialized_char(){}};` which I think will force the vector not to initialize anything. And then you would have to do a bunch of `reinterpret_casts` to interface with `read`. But is that really any cleaner than just using malloc?

Comment: You can write your own allocator.

Comment: @Evg, that's an option, but as my experience, custom alloctors some times make mistakes...

Comment: If you're reading a file, then the time "wasted" on zero initialisation is probably going to be insignificant. This is like shaving your legs in order to make your oil tanker accelerate faster.

Comment: @ravenisadesk, you can also use `std::unique_ptr<char[]>`.

Comment: What version of c++ is this? `make_unique<>(size_t)` wasn't added until c++14

Comment: @eerorika we don't actually know anything about this "file" that is being read from. It could just be a `shm_open`'ed file (or even just a pipe) and might be entirely resident in memory

Comment: No need to be paranoid. Write it, profile it and see if there's anything worth the time spent changing.

Comment: @SteveCox Actually, I think `std::make_unique<char[]>` still zero-initializes. Cppreference says that `std::make_unique<char[]>(size) ~> std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[size]()]` and `new T[n]()` (with parens) value-initializes the elements of the array which zero-initializes in the case of `char`. We need `std::make_unique_for_overwrite<char[]>(size) ~> std::unique_ptr<char[]>(new char[size])`, which doesn't give the parentheses which causes default-initialization of the `char`s which does nothing. `std::make_unique_for_overwrite` is in C++20. OFC, you could just construct it yourself.

Comment: @HTNW good point. And if you have to write the new itself, that seems to undermine OP's requirement that we "still using a vector, instead of using malloc"

Comment: @YunfeiChen The force required to accelerate an object increases with mass (`F = m*a`). Hair has mass. Shaving legs reduces your total mass. Reduction of mass reduces the force required to accelerate an object. Since the force generated by the engine is not affected by the shaving, the acceleration is increased by this reduction of mass. This assumes that you are aboard the tanker, and jettison the shavings. The point of the analogy is to evoke the feeling of pointlessly insignificant effort.

Comment: You could also use the shavings as additional reaction mass by throwing the shavings off the back of the ship. Net gain a couple grams over maybe a half million tonnes. [Totally worth the effort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarcasm).

Comment: @eerorika oh I did not think anyone would think of such a creative way to accerlate a ship lolz :)...

Comment: According to the comment in protobuf (src/google/protobuf/stubs/stl_util.h:47), google seems have some internal way to resize without initializing, I'm curious if anybody could figure out how.